# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2012: Unusually high memory usage (leaking?)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image: Task Manager]

1.3GB memory usage. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.
I don't do much - just editing a stored proc (no query running in the background, nor any query result).

I do notice though, it only happens occasionally - as if some kind of a garbage collection is kicking in then it'll return to its normal (around 100MB).

Any ideas / workaround / updates ?

- Just an update on this: it seems it doesn't happen anymore in SSMS 2014

Comment: Same problem here - are you running any third party plugins?

Comment: TFerrell - nope, no 3rd party whatsoever.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that if you turn off IntelliSense, the memory consumption subsides dramatically, and the software becomes much more responsive.  To turn it off, go to *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense*, and un-check the box.  Save your work and re-start the SSMS.

The major drawback is that you will loose both IntelliSense and Code Outlining.  Quite a bummer, but at least you can leave the SSMS open for days without problems.

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Comment: Turning off IntelliSense does not seem to save any memory in my case - it was approx. 280 MB after a few hours, now it is 230 after an hour. What seems to have a huge impact is custom color scheme: 1.7 GB with custom colors, 280 MB with default colors. This is in 2012 SSMS.

Comment: This works and you are correct, it is disabling a useful feature but I could not effectively work in ssms without doing this.

Comment: @Dave: Agreed - it makes it much harder to work with large SP files, but as I mentioned - I can leave the SSMS open with dozens of SP files open for days with no issues.  In the past (before SQL 2008), code outlining and Intellisense were not even available, yet we still were writing plenty of complex SQL code.  It is not as bad as it seems, but you will have to modify your work patterns a bit (make good use of code indents, modelling diagrams, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

This has been an Issue on a few version of SSMS on Stored Proc editing.

What fixed it for me in SSMS 17 was upping the intellisense "Maximum script size" from 1M to 5M. Unlimited is also available.
Option found: `Tools : Options : Text Editor : Transact-SQL : IntelliSense : Maximum script size`.
I'm not sure if this setting exists in lower versions of SSMS, please add a comment if it does.

This reduced the high cpu and memory leak (2.5G to 140M) to normal levels.

[ref to msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81a82fea-42c3-4d7e-9e2d-a2cf45f9c4d7/ssms-causes-high-cpu-utilization?forum=sqlkjappmsmgmt&prof=required)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when designing a stored procedure. When working on some dynamic SQL code, the process would run away and the application would become unresponsive. Once I turn off Intellisense, that behavior went away.